# fb like + send button

Tags: facebook, layout, facebook-like

I have the like and send button on the right side of my website.
When I click on either buttons, it displays a box but it extends towards the right thus giving me horizontal scroll bars.

Is there a way to have the box extend towards the left?

Many thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at this before and it is a pain in the £%^^&! Unfortunately because the elements are in an iframe you can't use your own stylesheets to overwite the styles and move the popup left. Instead what I have done in the past is mimic the send button to the left of the like button and use the FB.UI method to show a popup centred window like so:

```
<script>
  $(function () {

                   $('#sendbutton').click(function (e) {
                       e.preventDefault();
                       FB.ui({
                           method: 'send',
                           name: 'Blah blah blah',
                           description: 'Description',
                           link: 'http://www.example.com',
                           image: 'http://www.example.com/content/images/image.png' 
                       });
                       return false;
                   });

               });
 </script>

<a id="sendbutton" href=""><img src="@(Url.Content("~/Content/Images/send.png"))" /></a>
```

don't forget you will need to initialise the Facebook javascript API first:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: Wow, that just seems complicated.

Is there a way to just simply 'like' without opening the box?

Thanks for the quick reply, really appreciate it.

Comment: You can have the like button on it's own and not the send button. So when they click Like, it will simply update the like.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to just simply 'like' without opening the box?

No. You can try to hide the box by enclosing the iframe with a div and setting the div's height to something suitable and its overflow property to hidden, but that's about it. You might want to file a feature request with Facebook.